# set mandatory string datamember in wcf

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, datacontract

I want to set string DataMember as mandatory, I have set "IsRequired = true" but it is showing as optional in XML request.

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "tourinforequest")]
public class TourInfoRequest
{
    public TourInfoRequest()
    {
        Request = new TourInfoRequestRequestData();
    }
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public TourInfoRequestRequestData Request;
}

public class TourInfoRequestRequestData : BaseRequest
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true ), XmlElement(ElementName = "tourcode")]
    public string TourCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true), XmlElement(ElementName = "depdate")]
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you set `EmitDefault=false` in the `DataMember` attibute?

Comment: what is your`BaseRequest`?Also why're you using `XmlElement` attribute?You can use the `DataMember's` `Name` property instead.

Comment: `BaseRequest` contains other `DataMember` (s) which are common for few requests & I will use `Name` property instead of `XmlElement` thanks for this suggetion. But my main issue is still there.

Comment: It's strange. Can you share a full view of both the classes?

Comment: even if I remove `BaseRequest` still I have the same issue.